# Cannot get url from models.py for menu item

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-3.0

I create menu items fro my navigation but I can get everything from models, DB images(icons), name, but when I want to get URL nothing happening.

My views for menu

```
def index(request):
Post_list = BlogPost.objects.all()[:5]
Slider_item = HomePageSlider.objects.all()
menu_item = Menu.objects.all()
template_name = 'front/index.html'
return render(request, template_name, {"Post_list":Post_list,
                                      "data_item":Slider_item,
                                      "menu_item":menu_item,
                                            })
```

My template HTML

```
  {% for menu in menu_item %}
  <li class="mobile-menu-item">
    <a href="{{menu.0.Menu_url}}" class="mobile-menu-item-link">{{menu.Menu_name}}</a>
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
```

my models.py for Menu

```
from django.db import models


class Menu(models.Model):
    Menu_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    Menu_slug = models.SlugField(name="სლაგი",blank=True)
    Menu_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="menuimages")
    Menu_url = models.CharField(name="url",max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "მენიუ"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Menu_name
```

Answer (score 0):

in your models you have to define something shown as follows to call it in templates

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("your_detail_view", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

and call in templates

```
{{menu.get_absolute_url}}
```

or directly call url

```
{% url 'detail_view' pk=menu.pk %}
```

Comment: what means kwargs={"pk": self.pk}) this part

Comment: Bmons what's 'detail_view' ??

Comment: from list view you can redirect to a detail view, which will show each individual instances, if it is not there, you have to make it

Answer (score 0):

The only change you need to do is in your template, you don't have to do menu.0 as menu is the instance itself

```
  {% for menu in menu_item %}
  <li class="mobile-menu-item">
    <a href="{{menu.Menu_url}}" class="mobile-menu-item-link">{{menu.Menu_name}}</a>
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: i don't getting error it's just i cannot get charfield from database for url